# Simple phrase detection, split by phrase regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'd like to split up a string like:

Input: `Bangalore railway line of the Indian Railway. It comes under Nagpur division of the Central Railway.`

Output:

```
Bangalore 
railway 
line
Indian Railway 
comes
under 
Nagpur 
division
Central Railway
```

Notice that compound nouns would be kept together because they are Title Case.

I'm having trouble with the regex part specifically: `split(/(?=\s[a-z]|[A-Z]\s|\.)/)`

How do I get it to split on the 'water ꜜ Tor Museum' scenario ?

```
export function splitByPhrase(text: string) {
  const outputFreq = text
    .split(/(?=\s[a-z]|[A-Z]\s|\.)/)
    .filter(Boolean)
    .map((x) => x.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, "").trim())
    .filter((x) => !stopWords.includes(x));

  return outputFreq;
}

describe("phrases", () => {
  it("no punctuation", () => {
    expect(splitByPhrase("test. Toronto")).toEqual(["test", "Toronto"]);
  });
  it("no spaces", () => {
    expect(splitByPhrase(" test Toronto ")).toEqual(["test", "Toronto"]);
  });
  it("simple phrase detection", () => {
    expect(splitByPhrase(" water Tor Museum wants")).toEqual(["water", "Tor Museum", "wants"]);
  });
  it("remove stop words", () => {
    expect(splitByPhrase("Toronto a Museum with")).toEqual(["Toronto", "Museum"]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Alas, there is nothing simple about tokenization of natural languages, even English. JavaScript is particularly tricky because its regexes are non-Unicode by default, which means, among other things, that `\w` will not match common English characters such as "é". You might have better luck using `\S` and the `u` flag.

Comment: yeah I'd prefer a more robust solution but the only thing I could find was this and it looks like it takes some work to set up :/ https://github.com/JulianMH/NounPhraseJS

Comment: Anyway, *please* don't use `[a-z]` anywhere in natural language processing unless that's the language's actual alphabet — classical Latin maybe?

Comment: thankfully I am only looking at English text right now. but I should add some tests for non-\w characters. definitely a good thing to keep in mind

Comment: Yeah, at least something like `[a-zéàëçñ]` ; then of course you'll have trouble with (fortunately infrequent) dashes, and more trouble with apostrophes which can be used as quotation marks…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might add another alternative to split only when asserting what is on the left is not an uppercase char followed by lowercase chars and at the right there is no uppercase char.

```
(?= [a-z]|\.|(?<!\b[A-Z][a-z]*) (?=[A-Z]))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xk0KAv/1)

```js
const stopWords = [
  "of", "The", "It", "the", "a", "with"
];

function splitByPhrase(text) {
  return text
    .split(/(?= [a-z]|\.|(?<!\b[A-Z][a-z]*) (?=[A-Z]))/)
    .map((x) => x.replace(/[.,\/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()-]/g, "").trim())
    .filter((x) => !stopWords.includes(x)).filter(Boolean);
}

[
  "Bangalore railway line of the Indian Railway. It comes under Nagpur division of the Central Railway.",
  "test. Toronto",
  " test Toronto ",
  " water Tor Museum wants",
  "Toronto a Museum with"
].forEach(i => console.log(splitByPhrase(i)));
```

Answer (score 1):

For the case of slitting a lower case word before a Title Case word, I think `split(\s(?=[a-z]|[A-Z]\w+ |\.))` works for what you want.

https://regexr.com/59jfo

Input: `Bangalore railway line of the Indian Railway. It comes under Nagpur division of the Central Railway.`

Output:

```
Bangalore
railway
line
of
the
Indian Railway.
It
comes
under
Nagpur
division
of
the
Central Railway.
```

Comment: `\s(?=[a-z]|[A-Z]\w+ )|\.` is almost perfect. I have one case where it doesn't work: ` water Tor Museum wants` should have `Tor Museum` on the same line